# Passing object by value and modifying it in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

The book I'm using wants me to implement LIFO stacks using constructors in C++. The first implementation is fairly easy because it wants me to pass the object in a function by reference (so the code below has an additional & in pushexternal function). 
However, I don't know how to properly implement the second version of it. It wants me to make it by passing the object by value. Therefore, it creates a copy of the object and after using a push function on a stack, the pushed element is gone. I don't know how to properly do it when passing it by value. I was thinking about using a copy constructor somehow, but I've tried it and it doesn't seem to work...

This is the code that is written in the book. I'm not supposed to modify it, I can only write my own class / additional functions:

```
void pushexternal(Stack s, int a) {
    s.push(a);
}

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.push(0);
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    pushexternal(s, 3);
    pushexternal(s, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is a part of my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Stack {
public:
int ind;
int * arr;

Stack()
{
    arr = new int[25];
    ind = -1;
}
~Stack()
{
    delete [] arr;
}

void push(int val)
{
    arr[++ind] = val;
    cout << "Added " << arr[ind] << " to " << ind << endl;
}
};
```

I'm aware that passing by value is not recommended here, but I'm really wondering how can I make it work properly when pass by value is mandatory. The only thing that comes to my mind is writing some kind of a copy constructor...?
Of course, my code doesn't work here as it makes a copy that is supposed to push a variable, but when passing by value, it's gone when it exits the function...

The results of this program should look like this:

```
    Added 0 to 0
    Added 1 to 1
    Added 2 to 2
    Added 3 to 3
    Added 4 to 4
```

Comment: You could share the array pointed to by `arr` between instances and do some reference counting. You'll also need to share `int` though, perhaps as the last element of the array or a member of an implementation structure that will be shared. One would normally solve this with `std::shared_ptr` without reinventing the wheel. Anyways, show us what you've tried.

Comment: I wouldn't spend too much time on this. Collections by value are fairly useless and rarely used, at least they *should* be rarely used.

Comment: If you want to pass `Stack` by value to `pushexternal` (i.e. copy the stack), and have it still affect the original,  the only way to do this is to make the copy operation be a shallow copy, i.e all copies of the same `Stack` actually share a single instance of the stack data. For example, replace `int * arr` by `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> arr` .  However this is a terrible idea in terms of code design.

Comment: Maybe re-read the book and check that is exactly what they want you to do?  Does the book provide an "answer" later that you can check and see what they wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to allocate an extra member in your `arr` member, you could then use `arr[0]` instead of `ind` as your index. That way, even if your stack object is copied by value, the `arr` pointer will still point to the same memory.

Similar, possibly more complex solutions exist, involving having your object contain a pointer to a structure with both `ind` and `arr` in it.

Comment: `delete[] arr;` will leave other stacks with dangling pointers